# I am new in Programming , My table is existing but it shows unknown column

Tags: mysql, wordpress

```sql
    SELECT distinct(wpnxt.ID),
                   wpnxt.post_author,
                   wpnxt.post_date,
                   wpnxt.post_date_gmt,
                   wpnxt.post_content,
                   wpnxt.post_title,
                   wpnxt.post_excerpt,
                   wpnxt.post_status,
                   wpnxt.post_name,
                   wpnxt.post_modified,
                   wpnxt.post_modified_gmt,
                   wpnxt.post_parent,
                   wpnxt.post_password,
                   wpnxt.guid,
                   wpnxt.menu_order,
                   wpnxt.post_type,
                   wpnxt.post_mime_type,
                   wpnxt.comment_count
    FROM wp_12_posts AS wpnxt
    WHERE wpnxt.post_type = "post"
      AND wpnxt.post_status = "publish"
      AND wpnxt.ID != 340258
      AND wpnxt.post_password = ""
      AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM wp_12_postmeta WHERE (wpnxt.ID = wp_12_postmeta.post_id))
      AND EXISTS(SELECT *
                 FROM wp_12_term_relationships AS tr
                 WHERE (wp_12_postmeta.post_id = tr.object_id)
                   AND EXISTS(SELECT *
                              FROM wp_12_term_taxonomy AS tt
                              WHERE tt.taxonomy = "category"
                                AND (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
                                AND EXISTS(SELECT *
                                           FROM wp_12_terms t
                                           WHERE tt.term_id = t.term_id AND t.term_id IN (14092, 14092))))
      AND meta_key like "product_%_assigned"
    ORDER BY wpnxt.post_date DESC
    LIMIT 15
```

Unknown column 'wp_12_postmeta.post_id' in 'where clause' //This is error is shown

Comment: Ok. What is you question ?

Comment: I suspect this is the problem: `WHERE (wp_12_postmeta.post_id = tr.object_id)` but I'm really not sure

Comment: Yes on this point I getting error

Comment: @Xerror My Query seems to right then wp_12_postmeta.post_id shown unknown column

Comment: All those existence checks seem dubious - Joins would be the more obvious approach.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Comment: @Strawberry yes I know function in SQL is a different concept

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The  `wp_12_postmeta.post_id` in your code  `WHERE (wp_12_postmeta.post_id = tr.object_id)` is out of scope ..  (the table is not visibile/accesible in this where condition
looking to your code

Instead of several  exists on subquery that can't view the related  table you could use proper INNER JOIN

```
  SELECT  wpnxt.ID,
                   wpnxt.post_author,
                   wpnxt.post_date,
                   wpnxt.post_date_gmt,
                   wpnxt.post_content,
                   wpnxt.post_title,
                   wpnxt.post_excerpt,
                   wpnxt.post_status,
                   wpnxt.post_name,
                   wpnxt.post_modified,
                   wpnxt.post_modified_gmt,
                   wpnxt.post_parent,
                   wpnxt.post_password,
                   wpnxt.guid,
                   wpnxt.menu_order,
                   wpnxt.post_type,
                   wpnxt.post_mime_type,
                   wpnxt.comment_count
    FROM wp_12_posts AS wpnxt
    INNER JOIN wp_12_postmeta ON wpnxt.ID = wp_12_postmeta.post_id
    INNER JOIN wp_12_term_relationships tr ON wp_12_postmeta.post_id = tr.object_id
    INNER JOIN wp_12_term_taxonomy  tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id 
        AND tt.taxonomy = "category" ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
           AND t.term_id IN (14092, 14092)
    INNER JOIN wp_12_terms t ON 
    WHERE wpnxt.post_type = "post"
      AND wpnxt.post_status = "publish"
      AND wpnxt.ID != 340258
      AND wpnxt.post_password = ""
      AND meta_key like "product_%_assigned"
    ORDER BY wpnxt.post_date DESC
    LIMIT 15
```

Comment: Yes, It's working fine but the execution is slow. This approach will not work